Why is Spring Boot all ResponseStatusException error translated into 403
I've got a Spring boot application with this security config:
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                req.requestMatchers("/api/user/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

And in my application code I throw a ResponseStatusException:
return Optional.ofNullable(taskService.getTaskById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Task not found.")));

But the API response I get is always 403 error. Why isn't the response getting the 404 response code and the error message. I set in the exception?
When I get the 200, 201 code it sends the correct code and message, but the error code doesn't send error code or message.
Debug logs:
Securing POST /api/user/login
2024-08-25T17:09:54.016+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-08-25T17:09:54.016+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/user/login
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from user u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
2024-08-25T17:09:54.360+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
2024-08-25T17:09:54.360+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-08-25T17:09:54.360+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-08-25T17:09:54.360+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-08-25T17:09:54.360+05:30 DEBUG 6660 --- [backend] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access


Shpw your Spring Security DEBUG logs.

Duplicate of Spring Boot - Any exception in @RestController returns 403 - even if I throw a 404

By default Spring redirects requests to /error upon an error, but that endpoint requires authentication, as per your SecurityFilterChain definition.
You'd have to do something along the lines of:
req
    .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()

